# Issue querying data from external table in AWS redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have some data in parquet format in S3 location. While trying to read data via external table it gives This error:

```
abc.snappy.parquet has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://abc/data.**X**'. 
Column type: INT, Parquet schema:\noptional int64 **X** [i:3 d:1 r:0
```

(X represents the column name.)

Datatype defined in source for this column before putting data in S3  is `Number(10,0)` b and in external table data type is `INTEGER`.

I tried changing data in external table to INT8/BIGINT but result is same.

Need your expertise to resolve this.

Comment: Are you sure that the data doesn't have a decimal point in it?  Can you try to define the Redshift schema as Numeric to see if that clears up the error?

Comment: @ Bill ,thanks for response. it doesn't have any decimal value .actually its value  coming as null from source . i tried numeric  also but same result

Comment: I assume that the schema doesn't define this column as "not null".

Comment: @Bill, external table doesn't have any constraints.Still clueless on this behaviour

Comment: One issue with parquet is that it isn't easy to just look at it.  Do you have tools to extract the data for the column in question?

Comment: @bill , i tried reading parquet file , actually parquet is converting number data to int64/int32  based on data but these data is not allowed in redshift external table